# jQuery $.each loop: change object property

Tags: jquery, loops, object

I have a loop and a *blueprint* object. On each iteration I do a copy of the blueprint object and change the `options` property, but the final result is wrong. Here is the code

```
var combinations = [
  "10,2",
  "10,3",
  "10,4",
  "11,2",
  "11,3",
  "11,4",
  "12,2",
  "12,3",
  "12,4"
];

var blueprint = {
  'options': [],
  // other properties here, like this:
  /*
  'name': '',
  'price': '',
  'files': []
  */
};    

$.each(combinations, function(index, item){ 
  var obj = blueprint;
  obj.options = item.split(',');
  console.log(
    item, // ok
    obj.options, // ok
    obj // wrong obj.options!
  );

  // call a function with my object
  // myFunc(obj);
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle showing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanhalen/yrb2hu3z/) (I tried to use the internal StackOverflow snippet: the internal console gives right result, the browser console still shows wrong result, so I prefer an external Fiddle)

I could use `var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blueprint))` to avoid the object passed by reference, but this is far from ideal

Any solution, please?

Comment: `console.log(obj)` will show "Object >" then when you expand it, it will show the current value.  You only have *one* `var obj` so expanding it at the end will show the final result.   In chrome it even makes this clear by adding an `[i]` icon with tooltip: "Value below was expanded just now".

Comment: "You only have one `var obj`" = more specifically you only have one `blueprint` which obj *points to* - I've updated your fiddle so you can see what's going on clearer https://jsfiddle.net/e4h2dvjq/

Comment: *"On each iteration I do a copy of the blueprint object"* - this is where you're going wrong - you're not *copying* anything

Comment: This appears to "work" in the SO snippet because it expands it immediately rather than wait for you to click the expand button.